# Why is Regex.Replace with RegexOptions.IgnoreCase not working when I have "(" in the text?

Tags: c#, regexp-replace, ignore-case

I want to replace text with Regex, and to use RegexOptions.IgnoreCase,  but it is not working, when I have "(" in my text.

The code is:

```cs
var textToReplace = @" = CreateObject""(ADODB.Recordset)"";";
var retval = @"  RsBO = CreateObject""(adodb.recordset)"";";
var Newtext = " = new Recordset();";
Regex regexText = new Regex(textToReplace, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
retval = regexText.Replace(retval, Newtext);
```

The result is:

```cs
RsBO = CreateObject\"(adodb.recordset)\";
```

But I want to see:

```cs
RsBO = new Recordset();
```

If I remove the chars '(' and ')', it works.

Comment: Why use Regex at all - there is nothing Regex'ey in your string replacement, so you can simply do `retval.Replace(textToReplace, Newtext, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @KlausGütter, life is too short to not use Regex whenever you can! 

Answer (score 0):

There are a few special characters in your expression:

`(` and `)` delimits a capture group, while `.` represents any character (except line terminators).

Try escaping `)`, `(` and `.`:

```
var textToReplace = @" = CreateObject""\(ADODB\.Recordset\)"";";
```

Comment: Or let [Regex.Escape](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape) do the escaping for you.

Answer (score 0):

The intended replacement does not need a Regex at all because the string you are searching for does not use any of the pattern-matching features of a regular expression.

There is an overload of `string.Replace` where you can specify a string comparer which allows to do a case-insensitive match:

```
retval = retval.Replace(textToReplace, Newtext, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```